# processing a pcap/dmp file for time-to-live, user-agent, and OS

Tags: shell, grep, wireshark

I'm trying to generate a report of the number of clients/devices behind a given NAT gateway using the techniques discussed in [this paper](http://www.icir.org/gregor/papers/pam11-nat.pdf).

Basically **I need to write a script which looks for both 'User-Agent' and 'Time to live' at the same time**:

```
grep "    User-Agent:" *.txt

grep "    Time to live:" *.txt
```

Those are exactly how the lines are formatted in my output files and I'm happy having the text to the end of the line. They work separately but I haven't been successful in combining them.

My most recent attempts have been:

```
egrep -w '    User-Agent:'|'    Time to live:' ../*.txt
grep '    User-Agent:' ../*.txt' && grep '    Time to live:' ../*.txt
```

(I've been manually exporting text format files from Wireshark, if anyone has a suggestion for doing that via script I would be most grateful, I have a HUGE number of files to do this for.)

I looked for a similar thread but I didn't find one, if one already exists (as I expect) I apologize, whether someone can supply me a link to assistance or provide it I would be most grateful.

EDIT: I thought I should mention, the two phrases I'm looking for are on lines separated by other data so a solution would need to search for both in an example like so:

```
User-Agent:
blahblahblah:
halbhalbhalb:
Time to live:
```

egrep '    User-Agent:|    Time to live:' ../*.txt gives me:

```
desktop:~/Documents/scripts$ ./pcap_ttl_OS_useragent 
../scripttextfile1p.txt:    Time to live: 128
../scripttextfile1p.txt:    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/1.0\r\n
../scripttextfile2p.txt:    Time to live: 55
../scripttextfile3p.txt:    Time to live: 128
../scripttextfile3p.txt:    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/1.0\r\n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
egrep '    User-Agent:|    Time to live:' ../*.txt
```

should work.

I don't think the `-w` is getting you any "functionality".

Also, you want to quote the whole "extended" regular expression, inluding the `|` alternation character as one string.

Finally, it's not clear if your leading white space for each field is the result of a tab char or a group of spaces. That would affect the correct text string to put into the search patterns. To confirm white-space type, i like to use

```
grep 'User-Agent' ../*.txt | head -1 | cat -vet
```

will show ether

```
.....    User-Agent ....
```

OR

```
.....^IUser-Agent .....
```

The `^I` being the representation for the tab character.

IHTH

Comment: I appreciate the response, but unfortunately this looks for 'User-Agent:' or 'Time to live:' and not both.

Comment: so you want 'User Agent' AND 'Time to live' on the same line?

Comment: no, they would be on separate lines but both in the same file

Comment: I did a simplified test before posting my answer, and I was able to find two different targets in the same file, per my answer. The code above is a well known idiom for finding multiple targets in the same file and works for me all the time ;-) If you exporting wireshark files from Windows, and your processing the output on a Linux/Unix platform, you probably need to "convert" your files first, like `dos2unix logfile1 logfile2 ...` Else, please extend your question above with 5 lines of sample data, including some that should NOT match, and the expected output from that. Good luck.

Comment: Oh my goodness, right you are, I apologize. Seems I need to figure out what to do about the problem I just found.

Comment: yes no problem. post a new question re your new problem. Good luck.